# Linked List in Java, How to cast String array into List?

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list

Can you tell me what does this method return type is:

```
List<passenger> recommend(Car a, Driver b)  { ... }
```

I just want to know about List keyword. Is this standard linked list or soemthing else.
If i have objects of passenger type. How can I add them in a List?

Comment: Please, accept some answers for your previous questions by clicking a tick in the left of the answer.

Comment: I made a mistake by giving wrong email address. Now when i try to accept an answer it asks me to login and this email is invalid. What should i do? please tell me

Comment: Don't really know. Try to describe the problem on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: thanks for the information, i will do it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List in java is an interface. It means that it is not a concrete implementation, but the interface to it.

The concrete implementation the method can return can be `LinkedList`, `ArrayList` or any other class which implements the `List` interface. Read more in [`javadoc`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Basically, you add the elements to the list using methods `add` or `addAll`:

```
list.add(object);
list.addAll(anotherList);
```

Comment: That means i will have to initialize a specific type List and then add elements to it and then return it.

Answer (score 3):

List is an interface. it can be an ArrayList or what ever implements the List interface

```
List<passenger> list = new ArrayList<passenger>();
```

Basically, it contains a list of passengers.

Answer (score 2):

[`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface.  It defines a common list of operations that all list types support.

The actual list may be backed by a linked list ([`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)) or it may be backed by an array ([`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), or something else completely... you can find out if it's a `LinkedList` using the `instanceof` command (i.e. `if (myList instanceof LinkedList) { /* Do something */ }` )

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know about List keyword.

First of all, `List` is not a keyword.  It is the name of an interface.

So, what this method returns is a `List`.  Which means that you do not know the underlying representation of the list.

It may be a linked list, or an array list, or some other type of list.

The idea behind returning an interface instead of a specified implementation is it better abstracts out the details of the method implementation.  All that you need to know about the method is it will give you some object that behaves like a `List`.

See the [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) javadocs for more info.  You my be particularly interested in the list of all known implementing subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

```
Passenger p = new Passenger();
p.setId("1");
p.setName("xyz");
List<Passenger> passengerList = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
passengerList.add(p);
```

Comment: thanks a million times, actually this was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Can you suggest me of if for example i have to make many passenger objects and then add them to list. HOw can i made multiple objects in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an interface.  There are many implementations, one of which is `LinkedList`, it is all dependent on the concrete return type of your `recommend` method.

The `List` interface suggests an `add(Object)` method.  With generics, you can pass a `passenger` object into your `List` and ensure type safety.

Answer (score 0):

> How to cast String array into List?

You can't. The word you are looking for here is *convert.*